# what is the maximum extent of compressing a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Whenever I try to compress a PDF file to a lower possible size, by either using ghostscript or pdftk or pdfopt, I end up having a file near to half the size of original. But lately, I am getting files of size in 1000 MB range, which are compressing to say a few hundreds. Can we further reduce them?

The pdf is made from jpg images which are of higher resolutions, cant we reduce the size of those images and further bring in some more reduction in size?

Comment: It would be very helpful to know: exactly which ghostscript parameters are you employing to reduce the file size? (BTW, `pdfopt` is not meant to reduce the file size -- it does *linearize* [a.k.a. "web optimize"] the PDF. It results in internal restructuring so a viewer can start rendering the first pages of a remotely fetched file before all of the bytes have arrived locally. Also it frequently results in slightly larger file sizes...)

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, without degrading jpeg streams and loosing quality, you can try the special feature offered by

**Multivalent**

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355/Multivalent20060102.jar.html

```sh
java -cp path/to.../multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Compress -compact file.pdf
```

resulting output will be compressed in a special way. the resulting file needs Multivalent browser to be read again

it is unpredictable how much space you can save (many times you cannot save any further space)